# iam integrate Quickbooks free trial with salesforce

Tags: integration

I am integrating Quickbooks free trial with salesforce. It is working fine. I get the  `oauth_token_secret` and oauth_token
this my Response

`oauth_token_secret=<omitted>&oauth_token=qyprdEHzS8enkB3nkUCYZI0TJEj694mGhT300lxxj0KgdAp7&oauth_callback_confirmed=true`

finally oauth_token_secret and quickbook free trial company id using send the request is not working  this my final response

```
IntuitResponse time="2017-03-23T04:06:59.080-07:00" xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
    <Fault type="AUTHENTICATION">
        <Error code="3200">
            <Message>message=ApplicationAuthenticationFailed; errorCode=003200; statusCode=401</Message>
            <Detail>SignatureBaseString: GET&amp;https%3A%2F%2Fsandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com%2Fv3%2Fcompany%2F4401%2Fcompanyinfo%2F4401&amp;oauth_consumer_key%3DqyprdTFAgAdkwLnev2aEoRqKi0Dp1g%26oauth_nonce%3D1490267218%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1490267218%26oauth_token%3DqyprdGYoYoZ6gNalfluU88OWfbdM29ULguLm9PGVuxfHZrvn%26oauth_version%3D1.0</Detail>
        </Error>
    </Fault>
</IntuitResponse>
```

Comment: The `oauth_token_secret`, true to its name, is supposed to remain secret. Posting a secret key is never a good idea. As such, I've edited your question to remove it. I'd highly suggest generating a new oauth token secret.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to re-generate Oauth token again. Some time the OAuth token expires & you might need to use new one to connect to quickbooks online.